# R data.table. generate variable names

Tags: r, data.table

I want to generate a datatable with many columns, with names generated automatically, such as this:

```
data.table(paste0("A",10:24)=1:15)
```

or

```
data.table(paste0("A",10:24)=rep(runif(100), 15)
```

but I get this error:

Error: unexpected '=' in "data.table(paste0("A",10:24)="

How can I do it?

Comment: Create the table, then create the names with `setnames`.  Or, create a named list and coerce it to data.table

Comment: Could you post your solution with my example, please?

Comment: I think there is also some function similar to eval() or .() that allows to use expressions such as paste0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.  Here are three.  Create the table first, then set the names.  Or, create a named list and coerce it to data table.

```
setnames(as.data.table(as.list(1:15)), paste0("A", 10:24))[]
#    A10 A11 A12 A13 A14 A15 A16 A17 A18 A19 A20 A21 A22 A23 A24
# 1:   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15

do.call(data.table, setNames(as.list(1:15), paste0("A", 10:24)))
#    A10 A11 A12 A13 A14 A15 A16 A17 A18 A19 A20 A21 A22 A23 A24
# 1:   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15

as.data.table(setNames(as.list(1:15), paste0("A", 10:24)))
#    A10 A11 A12 A13 A14 A15 A16 A17 A18 A19 A20 A21 A22 A23 A24
# 1:   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15

## just for fun ...
fread(paste(c(paste0("A", 10:24), "\n", 1:15), collapse = " "))
#    A10 A11 A12 A13 A14 A15 A16 A17 A18 A19 A20 A21 A22 A23 A24
# 1:   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
```

Comment: Should I create the data.table first without any column names?

Comment: You can do it however you like, but yes that's how I would do it.